# Swift enumerate functions. How does it work behind?

Tags: swift, enumerate

> The **enumerate** function returns a **tuple** for each item in the array composed of the index and the value for that item.
>
> The **map** function returns an **array of elements** built from the results of applying a provided transforming closure for each element in the array.
>
> **Declaration**:
>
> ```
> func map<U>(transform: (T) -> U) -> [U]
> ```

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3]
numbers = map(numbers) { (index, element) in
    index + element
} //[1, 3, 5]
```

That is good. Works.

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3]
var result = map(enumerate(numbers)) { (index, element) in
    index + element
} //[1, 3, 5]
```

`map` expects an array as a first parameter, but I put there the tuple *as a result of enumerate fnction*.

The question is: **WHY IT WORKS?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works because in addition to array having a `map` method, there is a `map` function that takes any kind of `SequenceType`:

```
func map<S : SequenceType, T>(source: S, transform: (S.Generator.Element) -> T) -> [T]
```

This works not just with arrays, but any kind of sequence – strings, ranges, zipped pairs of sequences, and the result of `enumerate`, which is also a sequence:

```
// enumerate is a function that takes any kind of sequence, and returns 
// an EnumerateSequence object
func enumerate<Seq : SequenceType>(base: Seq) -> EnumerateSequence<Seq>
```

`EnumerateSequence` is a type that holds on to another sequence (in your case, the array `[1,2,3]`) and then when asked to generate an element, generates the next element from it’s contained sequence along with an incrementing number.

Comment: but how enumerate knows that it should return different tuple for every item?. It is called once, isn't?

Comment: see my edit: `enumerate` returns an object that implements `SequenceType`

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at the following answer: [What's the cleanest way of applying map() to a dictionary in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116271/whats-the-cleanest-way-of-applying-map-to-a-dictionary-in-swift)

The map function works on the tuple because it is using the map function from the swift standard library that works on any `SequenceType`. So it is actually using the index and value of the enumeration, which are the same as the index and element that the map function would use when looking at an array input.